# Soft keyboard doesn't hide on dialog dismiss when the dialog is called from another one

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I have a dialog for number input. When I call it from an activity and then dismiss it, soft keyboard hides. But there is a problem when I open it from another dialog. In this case, when I click outside of the dialog, my dialog closes but the keyboard is still visible, even calling `hideSoftKeyboard` explicitly doesn't solve the problem. But when I close the dialog using negative or positive button keyboard hides.

Here is my code:

```
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button, (dialog, which) -> {
    ...
    hideSoftKeyboard(editText, requireActivity());
});

builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_button, (dialog, which) -> hideSoftKeyboard(editText, requireActivity()));


public static void hideSoftKeyboard(View view, Context context) {
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: hide keyboard in _onDismissListener_  of dialog and use _dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);_ if method doesn't work

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: call directly from `builder.setNegativeButton`

Comment: It doesn't work. In this case keyboard is opened only when clicking the editText and still isn't closed on dialog dismiss